# CSS Vertical Align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bit stuck trying to align my social media icons vertically. I've tried vertical text-align and margin top and bottom 50% and they both don't work. I'm not sure how to achieve a vertically aligned ul class. I am using bootstrap, if this has an significance.

[image]

```
<footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Eat Sleep Kayak 2015</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-google fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>    

    @media (max-width:768px){
        footer {text-align: center; padding: 10px;}
    }

    @media (min-width: 769px) {
        footer .list-inline {
          float: right;
        }
        footer .copyright {
          float: left;
        }
    }

    footer {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #eee;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
    footer .list-inline {
      text-align: center;
    }
    footer .copyright {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case, `text-align: center;` won't help for vertically aligning elements.

If your footer has a fixed height, you could try :

```
footer .list-inline {
    line-height: 40px; /* adjust the value to the height of your footer */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a fixed footer height.

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
 .list-inline > li{`position:relative;top:50%` ; transform:translateY(-50%)}
```

this should do the trick;

---

**Explanation:**

`position:relative;top:50%` moves it down to the  middle , aligning the top of the picture.

`transform:translateY(-50%)` aligns the picture to the middle.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.